# How to use QRegExp when there is only one bckslash?

Tags: regex, qt, backslash, qregexp

I want to use QRegExp to detect Postgres like regular expressions. For QRegExp, doc says "To include a \ in a regexp, enter it twice, i.e. \"

Example: dollar amount:

`\$[0-9]+.[0-9][0-9]`

To successfully match this using QRegExp, it should be have two `\\` like:

`\\$[0-9]+.[0-9][0-9]`

This was an example, but is there a way to make sure it always matches correctly? I was thinking replacing all `\` with `\\`?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at QRegExp::setPatternSyntax, QregExp::escape or even QRegularExpression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the new improved QRegularExpression instead of QRegExp. It is much better than the old one in (almost) every regard.

About your question: You can use QRegularExpression::escape() to do the replacements you talked about. However this is not useful for an entire pattern string, since it replaces *all* reserved characters. However it is useful for sub-strings you can use to assemble a pattern.

Regarding your example... you simply need to take care of this manually. It is up to you to create valid patterns.

And note that there is additional C/C++ escaping taking place. This means to create two backslashes "\\" in C/C++ you need aktucally 4 of them "\\\\".